# For mobile app which one is better, Use domain name to connect to server or IP address?

Tags: android, performance, rest, dns, ip

In back-end side we have REST APIs, I want to connect to server from my android app. which one is better to use, Domain name or IP address?

Comment: what do you mean by "better"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that changing or even upgrading your server in the future (which can happen due to many reasons), may result in an IP change. Using the Domain Name is a better option.